# How to pass data to the redirected route after Bell authentication?

Tags: hapi.js

I have an Hapi.JS application that authenticates with a provider via Bell plugin.

Authentication works as expected. I check for an account in our DB associated with the Bell credentials upon successful login. If no user account is associated, I redirect to the registration page.

The problem is I can't pass user's profile data to the registration route. Even if I set a cookie, it is lost when redirected to the registration route.

I know I can use hapi-auth-cookie but I am planning to use JWT authentication and I don't want to add a new plugin just for passing basic user info to a specific route.

Do you have an idea how can I make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Cookies don't just get "lost".You choices are 1) set a cookie with some session data or 2) hand the user a JWT (or other token) to use on subsequent requests. Obviously 1 is simpler because you have browser support without having to have the client manually store the token. The principle is similar though.

Comment: I have a simple example that might be useful to you: https://github.com/mtharrison/hapi.js-in-action/tree/master/CH09%20-%20Authentication%20and%20Security/9.2/9.2.3

Comment: That's the part I could not understand. Somehow it is not set, or carried upon redirect. I will use JWT for normal operations but in this specific case, I just want to pass Bell login data to registration page for filling up some fields, etc. A new account will be created so the username is not available when I set the cookie and using JWT for temporarily storing this daha seems like an overkill. Instead of using hapi-auth-cookie as in your example, I used .state function on reply to set a temporary cookie just for registration.

Comment: Alternatively, you could skip the redirect+cookie altogether and render the registration form on your OAuth callback route?